# Python time.sleep() DRY issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, sleep

i am making a tiny terminal game.
based of many text with yes/no questions
and i must use "time.sleep()" many times for delay effect.
i try to follow the DRY(Dont Repeat Yourself) principle.
how can i avoid using this method many times?

```
print('some texts')
time.sleep(1)

if True:
   print('some texts')
   time.sleep(1)

print('some texts')
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: If you have an array of messages you could use a `for` instead of printing them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate your `print` and `time.sleep` calls into a function that you define which accepts a string (to print) and an integer (to pass to time.sleep)